Operation `.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms - Next.js Mongoose
In my NextJS Project, I'm working on a newsletter application. My database is called Datastax Astra. I have developed the logic to save the database file. however, I continue to receive a 1000 ms buffering issue. I looked and tried, but it didn't yield any results.
db.ts
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { driver, createAstraUri } from "stargate-mongoose";

export const connectDb = async () => {
  try {
    const uri = createAstraUri(
      process.env.ASTRA_DB_API_ENDPOINT!,
      process.env.ASTRA_DB_APPLICATION_TOKEN!
    );
    if (mongoose.connection.readyState !== 0) {
      await mongoose.disconnect();
    }
    mongoose.set("autoCreate", true);
    mongoose.setDriver(driver);

    await mongoose
      .connect(uri, { isAstra: true })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("Connected");
      })
      .catch((r) => {
        console.log(r);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};


I made a connection function to the database in the code above so that I could be called during the connection and raise an error if one happened.
This is my save email code, which creates a connection and uses the database connection function from db.ts files to put data in the database.
Save_Email.ts
"use server";

import Email from "@/models/email.model";
import { connectDb } from "@/shared/libs/db";

export const saveEmail = async ({
  title,
  content,
  newsLetterOwnerId,
}: {
  title: string;
  content: string;
  newsLetterOwnerId: string;
}) => {
  try {
    await connectDb();
    const email = await Email.findOne({
      title,
      newsLetterOwnerId,
    });

    if (email) {
      await Email.findByIdAndUpdate(email._id, {
        content,
      });
      return { message: "Email updated successfully!" };
    } else {
      await Email.create({
        title,
        content,
        newsLetterOwnerId,
      });
      return { message: "Email saved successfully!" };
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};


For the email, I had also developed an email schema. Its code is provided below.
Schema
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const emailSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
    },
    content: {
      type: String,
    },
    newsLetterOwnerId: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const Email = mongoose.models.Email || mongoose.model("Email", emailSchema);
export default Email;


I attempted to create an email collection in my online Astra database, but it was completely unsuccessful. I must save the email info online in my Astra database. but it's not, and the error that follows indicates this.
Connected
MongooseError: Operation `emails.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\Portfolio\Newsletter\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)


If I remember correctly, mongoose.connect doesn't actually execute the network connection, it just gets everything ready, but the underlying driver doesn't actually set up the connection until you try to use it.  You can check that with mongoose.connection.readyState.  The problem may be with establishing the connection and not actually with the findOne call.

As @Joe has rightly pointed it out, the issue is with the server connection.
The following text will explain the settings related with this case, also show the issue in detail. It includes multiple solutions demoed with codes as well.
In connection with this case, there are two settings to discuss.

bufferCommands & bufferTimeoutMS
serverSelectionTimeoutMS

1. bufferCommands & bufferTimeoutMS
bufferCommands is a mongoose specific setting to deal with the possible intermittent disconnections with a MongoDB server. It will let the application to wait and retry the model methods when the server connection resumes. However it will timeout and throw an error if the connection does not restore within bufferTimeoutMS which is 10 seconds by default.
This is what now happens in this case. The application had cached - more specifically the method findOne - for 10 seconds, and then aborted by throwing the error.
2. serverSelectionTimeoutMS
This is a setting mongoose passes on to the Mongo driver program. It sets the seconds the driver program will try looking for a server to send any given operation. The default value is 30 seconds.
The issue:
By default, the serverSelectionTimeoutMS is 3 times higher than bufferTimeoutMS. Therefore bufferTimeoutMS will expire first. This will suppress the real cause of failure which is the serverSelectionTimeoutMS timeout.
Now there are 3 options at least, to take this case forward

Disabling bufferCommands
Lowering serverSelectionTimeoutMS than bufferTimeoutMS
Increasing bufferTimeoutMS than serverSelectionTimeoutMS

Applying option 1: Disabling bufferCommands - example
The following temporary setting will let the system wait for 30 seconds and then throw the actual cause of error.
const schema = new Schema({ /* ... */ }, { bufferCommands: false });

Applying option 2: Lowering serverSelectionTimeoutMS than bufferTimeoutMS - example
Please apply this option, If you find the waiting of 30 seconds in option 1 is little longer than needed for debugging purposes. The following temporary setting will let the system wait for 5 seconds and then throw a similar error as in option 1.
mongoose.connect(uri, { serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000 }); // Timeout after 5s instead of 30s

Sample code: Option 1 - Connection error thrown after 30 seconds
// Please note there is no MongoDB server at the given URL

import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

await main().catch((err) => {
   console.log(`Error thrown: ${new Date()}`);
   console.log(err);
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => { console.log(err);});

async function main() {
   const uri = 'mongodb://127.1.0.1:27017/test';

   console.log(`Connecting: ${new Date()}`);
   await mongoose.connect(uri);

   const someSchema = new Schema({ somekey: String }, { bufferCommands: false });
   const SomeModel = mongoose.model('SomeModel', someSchema);
   await SomeModel.find();
}
   
OUTPUT: Connection error thrown after 30 seconds

Connecting. : ...   13:37:15 hh:mm:ss ...
Error thrown: ...   13:37:45 hh:mm:ss ...
Error: MongooseServerSelectionError: connection timed out
…

Sample code: Option 2 - Connection error thrown after 5 seconds
// Please note there is no MongoDB server at the given URL

import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

await main().catch((err) => {
   console.log(`Erron thrown: ${new Date()}`);    
   console.log(err);
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
console.log(err);
});

async function main() {
   const uri = 'mongodb://127.1.0.1:27017/test';

   console.log(`Connecting: ${new Date()}`);
   await mongoose.connect(uri, {
   serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000,
   });

   const someSchema = new Schema({ somekey: String });
   const SomeModel = mongoose.model('SomeModel', someSchema);
   await SomeModel.find();
}

OUTPUT: Connection error thrown after 5 seconds

Connecting. : ... 13:33:35 hh:mm:ss ...
Error thrown: ... 13:33:40 hh:mm:ss ...
Error: MongooseServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 5000 ms
...

Caution and Request:
Please note that the options discussed over here are just for debugging purposes. Once the connection issue has been sought out, the changes in this regard are to be reverted.
To make permanent changes based on the needs of an application, please go through the original documentation over here :

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html.

