Error: Failed to update MongoDB: MongooseError: Operation `communities.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
I've a MongoDB database with the following schema in the file community.model.js:
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const CommunitySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    admin: {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "user",
    },
    imdb: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      maxLength: [25, "Max length 25"]
    },
    poster: {
      type: String,
      maxLength: [250, "Max length 250"]
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    //  minlength: [4, "Must be at least 4 characters long"],
     // maxlength: [30, "Must be no more than 30 characters long"],
    },
    bio: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
     // maxLength: [250, "Must be at most 250 characters long"],
    },
    posts: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "post",
      },
    ],
    subscribedBy: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "user",
      },
    ],
    subscriberCount: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);


module.exports = mongoose.model("community", CommunitySchema);

I have made a script to transfer data from a MySql database to MongoDB:
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Community = require("../model/community.model");
const mysql = require("mysql2");
const config = require("./config/config");

const mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: config.database.host,
  user: config.database.user,
  password: config.database.password,
  database: config.database.databaseName,
});
(async() => {
  await db()

 })()

const schemaFields = config.mysqlQueryColumns.reduce((acc, field) => {
  acc[field.name] = field.type;
  return acc;
}, {});


const updateMongo = async () => {

  try {
    
    if (mongoose.connection.readyState !== 1) {

      console.log("MongoDB connection is not open. Trying to connect...");
      await mongoose.connect(config.database.mongodb);
 
   
      console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
    }
   
    const columns = config.mysqlQueryColumns.map((field) => field.name).join(", ");

    mysqlConnection.query(`SELECT ${columns} FROM ${config.table_name} LIMIT 10`,(err, results) => {

        if (err) {
          console.error(`MySQL query error: ${err}`);
          return;
        }

        results.forEach(async (row) => {
          try {
           
            let updateData = {};
            config.mysqlQueryColumns.forEach((field) => {
              updateData[field.name] = row[field.name];

            });
          console.log(updateData);
          
           await Community.create({

                name : updateData.titol,
                bio: updateData.event,
                subscribedBy : ["661d5aef399b7e21da05b2a1"],
                admin: "661d5aef399b7e21da05b2a1"
          //     admin: userId,
          //      subscribedBy: [userId],
              
           });
       
          } catch (err) {
            console.error(`Failed to update MongoDB: ${err}`);
          }
        });
        
        console.log("Data updated to MongoDB");
      });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Failed to update MongoDB:", err);
  }
};

async function db() {
await  mongoose.connect(config.database.mongodb).then(() => {
      console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
     
      updateMongo();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("MongoDB connection error:", err);
    });
}

setInterval(() => {
  console.log("Updating MongoDB...");
  if (mongoose.connection.readyState !== 1) {
   db();

  } else {
    updateMongo();
  }
}, config.fetch_time || 10 * 1000 * 60);

It connects correctly to the MongoDB database, the query to the Mysql database is also successful but when doing Community.create the following error occurs:
Failed to update MongoDB: MongooseError: Operation communities.insertOne() buffering timed out after 10000ms
The MySQL records:
{
  imdb: 'tt0082533',
  titol: 'Aullidos (1981)',
  poster: 'https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/dEFMku7o825YhyUEHSlkvLDz1Dt.jpg',
  event: 'After a bizarre and near fatal encounter with a serial killer, a newswoman is sent to a rehabilitation center whose inhabitants may not be what they seem.'
}


try logging the connection ready state just before the call to create

Following up with what Joe said - mongoose will let you start using it while the connection is still establishing (buffering). https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html The issue could be that the connection is not ever fully made.

Please refer to this post - it has a detailed explanation of the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78318050/operation-findone-buffering-timed-out-after-10000ms-next-js-mongoose/78320095#78320095
