MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms while connecting with nextjs
I am trying to connect mongoDB with my nextjs (14) project through mongoose. But I am encountering problem with connecting mongoDB with  nextjs (14).
It's a simple nextjs form project to push email and username to my database and then read it to show those info. When I try to submit data to my database it show's this error ...
MongooseError: Operation users.insertOne() buffering timed out after 10000ms
at Timeout. (D:\joy\nextJs\week nine\data-fetching\fetch-data\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
This is my connectMongo function to connect mongoDB with nextjs.
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const MONGO_URI = process.env.MONGO_URI;
const cached = {};

async function connectMongo() {
  if (!MONGO_URI) {
    throw new Error(
      "Please define the MONGO_URI environment variable inside .env.local"
    );
  }
  if (cached.connection) {
    return cached.connection;
  }
  if (!cached.promise) {
    const opts = {
      bufferCommands: false,
    };
    cached.promise = mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, opts);
  }
  try {
    cached.connection = await cached.promise;
  } catch (e) {
    cached.promise = undefined;
    throw e;
  }
  return cached.connection;
}
export default connectMongo;

This is UserShema model...
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: "Anonymous",
    min: 2,
    max: 100,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    match: [
      /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/,
      "Please fill a valid email address",
    ],
    min: 2,
    max: 100,
  },
});

const User = mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

export default User;


and this is my form component...
import connectMongo from "@/dbConnect/connectMongo";
import User from "@/models/User";

export default function NewUserForm() {
  const addUser = async (formData) => {
    "use server";

    const name = formData.get("name");
    const email = formData.get("email");
    const userData = {
      name,
      email,
    };
    try {
      await connectMongo;
      await new User(userData).save();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <form action={addUser}>
      <div>
        <input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Name' />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='Email' />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}


** point to be noted: I changed my local DNS to google DNS (8.8.8.8) and in mongoAtlas network access I allowed all user to access.**

The following post has detailed the same case, provided solutions as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78318050/operation-findone-buffering-timed-out-after-10000ms-next-js-mongoose/78320095#78320095
