MongooseError: Operation `admins.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
Everything works perfectly in localhost but after deploying it on cPanel I'm getting this error:
Operation xyz.findOne() buffering timed out after 10000ms.
I have tried all possible solutions available on internet in last 3 days  but no luck. :(
//index.js
const express = require("express");
require("dotenv").config();
const cors = require("cors");
const { fileURLToPath } = require("url");
const path = require("path");
const { connectDb } = require("./db/db.js");
const adminRouter = require("./routes/admin/admin.routes.js");
const candidateRouter = require("./routes/candidate/candidate.routes.js");
const employerRouter = require("./routes/employer/employer.routes.js");

connectDb(); //db connection

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// Serve static files from the build directory
app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));

// API routes
app.use("/api", adminRouter);
app.use("/api", candidateRouter);
app.use("/api", employerRouter);

// Serve the main HTML file for any other routes
app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
});

console.log("PORT:", process.env.PORT);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});


db.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const url = process.env.MONGODB_URL;
module.exports.connectDb = async () => {
  await mongoose
    .connect(url)
    .then(() => console.log("MongoDB connected"))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};


environment variable
MONGODB_URL=mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.ulebre1.mongodb.net/jobportal?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0

I tried below:

importing mongoose models in index.js
whitelisted IP
reset the Mongodb configuration
changed code according to the available solutions.
I'm already using aync and await.


Just a guess, but have you tried changing the mongodb username/password? The env variable you posted has a dummy username/password. In the future you should not post your database connection info since people might abuse it.

@MadsHougesen yes I did it. I intentionally made it dummy. Please help me out.

Please see if following post is useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78318050/operation-findone-buffering-timed-out-after-10000ms-next-js-mongoose/78320095#78320095
