Mongodb & Express, post error message: buffering timed out after 10000ms
Nearly all answers I've found to this issue result in people saying "you aren't connected to MongoDB" or "you need to create an async await to connect to the database," but I am connected to my database & I am using an async await function. Please help me resolve my case.
Error:
{
  "message": "Operation `scales.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms"
}

My Files
db.js
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require('mongodb');
const { endpoint } = require("./config")

//test: add scale model and see if this fixes connection issues
const ScaleScheme = require('../app/models/Scale')

// Create a MongoClient with a MongoClientOptions object to set the Stable API version
const client = new MongoClient(endpoint, {
serverApi: {
version: ServerApiVersion.v1,
strict: true,
deprecationErrors: true,
}
});

async function connectDB() {
try {
// Connect the client to the server (optional starting in v4.7)
await client.connect();
// Send a ping to confirm a successful connection
await client.db("admin").command({ ping: 1 });
console.log("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!");

       const dbName = "all-music-is-microtonal";
       const collectionName = "scales";
     
       // Create references to the database and collection in order to connectDB
       const database = client.db(dbName);
       const collection = database.collection(collectionName);

} finally {
// Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
await client.close();
}
}

module.exports = connectDB;

server.js
const connectDB = require('./db');
//Express Node Intro: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Introduction
//Express simplifies APIs and handeling of HTTP request/response
const express = require('express');
const routes = require('../routeTest')
const app = express();

const { port } = require('./config');

// Connect Database
connectDB().catch(console.dir);

// allows for post 'req.body.propertyName' to work
app.use(express.json())
// use exported routes
app.use('/api', routes)

// Connect to localhost port
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello world!'));
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));

routeTest.js
//Article Reference: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/build-a-restful-api-using-node-express-and-mongodb/
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
//Load Scale Schema
const ScaleSchema = require('./app/models/Scale')

// ERROR when running post method:
//   {
//       "message": "Operation `scales.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms"
//    }
//Post Method
router.post('/scale', async (req, res) => {
const scaleData = await new ScaleSchema ({
name: req.body.name,
author: req.body.author,
isPreset: req.body.isPreset,
scaleDegrees: req.body.scaleDegrees,
sustainMode: req.body.sustainMode,
startingFreq: req.body.startingFreq,
periodRatio: req.body.periodRatio,
})

    try {
        console.log(scaleData)
        await scaleData.save();
        res.status(200).json(saveNewScale)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({message: error.message})
    }

})

//Get all Method
router.get('/scales', (req, res) => {
res.send('Get all scales')
})

//Get by ID Method
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
res.send('Get scale by ID')
})

//Update by ID Method
router.patch('/:id', (req, res) => {
res.send('Update scale by ID')
})

//Delete by ID Method
router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
res.send('Delete scale by ID')
})

module.exports = router;

I am expecting a new scale to be saved to the database.

Hi, Please see this post which addresses the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78318050/operation-findone-buffering-timed-out-after-10000ms-next-js-mongoose/78320095#78320095

For anyone that might come to this later: I learned the issue had to do with my Schema/Model file using mongoose, and my database file connecting via MongoDB client. I had to switch over to mongoose.connect in my database file to connect the two.
